# LINQ query returning NULL ASP-NET-CORE MVC

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing a LINQ query to fetch data from an entity Test Runs using the DBContext, but it returns a null value. What could be the possible reasons for this?

This is the query:

```
var testResults = _context.TestRuns.Where(e => e.Status.Equals("Running") && e.Deleted == false).ToList();
```

Comment: Did you give error? this query can't result Null at all

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour I dont get an error, it just throws a System.Exception and when I set a breakpoint at the line, it fails at this query. The value in testResults is null and the exception says, **data values cannot be null**

Comment: Try `e.Status == "Running"`

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour I tried it, still the same exception! What else could be a reason for this?p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because `Status` or `Deleted` are nullable columns in database but you didn't define them as nullable in `TestRun` model